# how the TFIDF values are transformed

Tags: python-2.7, tfidfvectorizer

I am new to NLP, please clarify on how the TFIDF values are transformed using fit_transform.

Below formula for calculating the IDF is working fine,
 log (total number of documents + 1 / number of terms occurrence + 1) + 1

EG: IDF value for the term "This" in the document 1("this is a string" is 1.91629073

After applying fit_transform, values for all the terms are changed, what is the formula\logic used for the transformation

TFID = TF * IDF

EG: TFIDF value for the term "This" in the document 1 ("this is a string") is 0.61366674

How this value is arrived, 0.61366674?

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
import pandas as pd

d = pd.Series(['This is a string','This is another string',
               'TFIDF Computation Calculation','TFIDF is the product of TF and IDF'])


df = pd.DataFrame(d)

tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()

tfidf = tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(df[0])


print (tfidf_vectorizer.idf_)

#output
#[1.91629073 1.91629073 1.91629073 1.91629073 1.91629073 1.22314355 1.91629073 
#1.91629073 1.51082562 1.91629073 1.51082562 1.91629073 1.51082562]

##-------------------------------------------------

##how the above values are getting transformed here 

##-------------------------------------------------


print (tfidf.toarray())


#[[0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.49681612  0.         
#0.         0.61366674 0.         0.         0.     0.61366674]
# [0.         0.61422608 0.         0.         0.         0.39205255
#  0.         0.         0.4842629  0.         0.         0.  0.4842629 ]
# [0.         0.         0.61761437 0.61761437 0.         0.
#  0.         0.         0.         0.         0.48693426 0.  0.        ]
# [0.37718389 0.         0.         0.         0.37718389 0.24075159
#  0.37718389 0.37718389 0.         0.37718389 0.29737611 0.37718389  0.        ]]
```

Answer (score 1):

It's normed TF-IDF vectors because by default `norm='l2'` according to the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html). So in the output of `tfidf.toarray()` each element on level 0 / row of the array represents a document and each element of level 1 / column represents a unique word with the sum of squares of vector elements for each document being equal to 1, which you can check by printing `print([sum([word ** 2 for word in doc]) for doc in tfidf.toarray()])`.

> norm : ‘l1’, ‘l2’ or None, optional (default=’l2’)
>   Each output row will have unit norm, either: * ‘l2’: Sum of squares of vector elements is 1. The cosine similarity between two
>   vectors is their dot product when l2 norm has been applied. * ‘l1’:
>   Sum of absolute values of vector elements is 1. See
>   preprocessing.normalize

```
print(tfidf) #the same values you find in tfidf.toarray() but more readable
output: ([index of document on array lvl 0 / row], [index of unique word on array lvl 1 / column]) normed TF-IDF value
(0, 12) 0.6136667440107333  #1st word in 1st sentence: 'This'
(0, 5)  0.4968161174826459  #'is'
(0, 8)  0.6136667440107333  #'string', see that word 'a' is missing
(1, 12) 0.48426290003607125 #'This'
(1, 5)  0.3920525532545391  #'is'
(1, 8)  0.48426290003607125 #'string'
(1, 1)  0.6142260844216119  #'another'
(2, 10) 0.48693426407352264 #'TFIDF'
(2, 3)  0.6176143709756019  #'Computation'
(2, 2)  0.6176143709756019  #'Calculation'
(3, 5)  0.2407515909314943  #'is'
(3, 10) 0.2973761110467491  #'TFIDF'
(3, 11) 0.37718388973255157 #'the'
(3, 7)  0.37718388973255157 #'product'
(3, 6)  0.37718388973255157 #'of'
(3, 9)  0.37718388973255157 #'TF'
(3, 0)  0.37718388973255157 #'and'
(3, 4)  0.37718388973255157 #'IDF'
```

Because it's normed TF-IDF values the sum of squares of vector elements will be qual to 1. E.g. for the first document at index 0, the sum of squares of vector elements will be equal to 1: `sum([0.6136667440107333 ** 2, 0.4968161174826459 ** 2, 0.6136667440107333 ** 2])`

You can turn off this transformation by setting `norm=None`.

```
print(TfidfVectorizer(norm=None).fit_transform(df[0])) #the same values you find in TfidfVectorizer(norm=None).fit_transform(df[0]).toarray(), but more readable
output: ([index of document on array lvl 0 / row], [index of unique word on array lvl 1 / column]) TF-IDF value
(0, 12) 1.5108256237659907 #1st word in 1st sentence: 'This'
(0, 5)  1.2231435513142097 #'is'
(0, 8)  1.5108256237659907 #'string', see that word 'a' is missing
(1, 12) 1.5108256237659907 #'This'
(1, 5)  1.2231435513142097 #'is'
(1, 8)  1.5108256237659907 #'string'
(1, 1)  1.916290731874155  #'another'
(2, 10) 1.5108256237659907 #'TFIDF'
(2, 3)  1.916290731874155  #'Computation'
(2, 2)  1.916290731874155  #'Calculation'
(3, 5)  1.2231435513142097 #'is'
(3, 10) 1.5108256237659907 #'TFIDF'
(3, 11) 1.916290731874155  #'the'
(3, 7)  1.916290731874155  #'product'
(3, 6)  1.916290731874155  #'of'
(3, 9)  1.916290731874155  #'TF'
(3, 0)  1.916290731874155  #'and'
(3, 4)  1.916290731874155  #'IDF'
```

Because every word just appears once in each document, the TF-IDF values are the IDF values of each word times 1:

```
tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(norm=None)
tfidf = tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(df[0])
print(tfidf_vectorizer.idf_)
output: Smoothed IDF-values
[1.91629073 1.91629073 1.91629073 1.91629073 1.91629073 1.22314355
 1.91629073 1.91629073 1.51082562 1.91629073 1.51082562 1.91629073
 1.51082562]
```

I hope, the above is helpful to you.

Unfortunately, I cannot reproduce the transformation, because

> The cosine similarity between two vectors is their dot product when l2
>   norm has been applied.

seems to be an additional step. Because the TF-IDF values will be biased by the number of words in each document when you use the default setting `norm='l2'`, I would simply turn this setting off by using `norm=None`. I figured out, that you cannot simply do the transformation by using:

```
tfidf_norm_calculated = [
    [(word/sum(doc))**0.5 for word in doc]
    for doc in TfidfVectorizer(norm=None).fit_transform(df[0]).toarray()]
print(tfidf_norm_calculated)
print('Sum of squares of vector elements is 1: ', [sum([word**2 for word in doc]) for doc in tfidf_norm_calculated])
print('Compare to:', TfidfVectorizer().fit_transform(df[0]).toarray())
```